# Org mode export subtree to new org file - option missing?

Tags: org-mode, exporting

in the manual I see the possibility to export a subtree to a new `org` file, [here](https://orgmode.org/manual/Org-Export.html).
This possibility is also referenced in [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/40870/under-org-mode-save-section-of-file-to-another-file) StackExchange answer.
However, when I hit `C-x C-e` in my system, the `O` option is neither recognized nor displayed in the `Dispatcher` window:

[image]

Can anybody explain why this is the case? The answer dates 2018, has anything changed in the mean time? Also the manual reports it so I'm thinking it might be some other effect taking place.

`M-x org-version` gives 9.5.2

`M-x emacs-version` gives 26.3

Answer (score 2):

Following the hint of this [post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55661/org-export-dispatcher-missing-options) I've just tried `M-x customize` on the `org-export-backends` variable, where the `org` option was unticked.

Ticking it activated the option.

Comment: The Org export backend is indeed not active by default.